# How to get products from Shopify API NodeJS

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

A simple question:
How do i get all the products in my store and log them to the console?

this:

```
     async function test() {
        fetch("/products")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

returns an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: you can try "/products.json"

Comment: Doesn't work either